# OnBackPressed is not getting fired when keyboard is opened

Tags: android

I want to override onBackPressed method but it is not getting fired when keyboard is opened.

Comment: Because "back" closes the keyboard first. This is the defined behavior and shouldn't be changed...

Comment: but i have to finish activity on first time when back key is pressed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should be extremely careful with that behavior. You are implementing something that the user is not used to plus the newer API devices aren't even showing a "back" button anymore when you have the keyboard out. Instead it is a "down arrow" to show that the keyboard will be closed. See this image: http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2012-12-20-14.18.11-e1356044525795.png So basically you are breaking the UX for your users. Who ever gives you this requirement has no clue. Argue with him! You would be on the right side of this fight!

Comment: Show him my comments if that helps your argumentation.

Comment: You could consider using the enter/done key of the keyboard as trigger, example here: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-and-tracking-done-action-of-android-soft-keyboard-using-ime-options-for-edittext/